# Haproxy config to proxy http and ws to diffrent servers

Tags: http, websocket, haproxy

I am trying haproxy to set up a proxy based on connection type. If HTTP then it should go to the localhost HTTP server. If its a web socket then it should go to another server.
The problem is the socket server `solana.abc.com/94b23a62`  94b23a62 is for auth. with this config, every req is going to the localhost HTTP server.

with TCP config it only works with the base URL.if I add `/94b23a62` it simply gives an error.

with this config

````
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon


defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  300000
        timeout server  300000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend wss-in
    bind *:4000
    mode http
    acl is_websocket hdr(Upgrade) -i WebSocket
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto http
    use_backend solana-ws if is_websocket

frontend https-in
    bind *:4000 
    mode http
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https
    default_backend solana-http


backend solana-http
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    server solana 127.0.0.1:4001 check

backend solana-ws
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    http-request set-path /94b23a62
    http-request set-header Host solana.abc.com
    server solana-ws solana.abc.com:80 check```
````